# Why GIT command line stopped working suddenly with "SSL Certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate"

Tags: git, github, certificate

I have basic idea about GIT. I was able to clone, add, pull, commit, push and run all commands successfully in my GIT windows client, through command line, which suddenly has stopped working. I am able to clone from eclipse, using personal access token, but cloning from command line(or any other command), gives above issue. I modified my github password recently. Also I checked that .gitconfig file has

```
             [http]
             sslCAInfo = <Folder_Name>\\tools\\cacerts\\curl-ca-bundle.crt
```

and crt file is present in the location, and not modified recently, while I had cloned from command line until recently

my .ssh files (public and private) are also available, and not modified/corrupted

I have deleted my git entry from known_hosts file

Please suggest, how to fix this issue?

Comment: Are you attempting to connect to GitHub, or another server?  Is your network using a proxy or SSL MITM device, or are you just trying to make a regular connection?  What does `git config -l | grep -i backend` produce?

Comment: yes my network is using proxy. no result from `git config -l | grep -i backend`

Comment: @bk2204 its still not resolved, do you have any idea?

Comment: I don't.  If you're trying to connect to GitHub, your proxy is tampering with your connection, and perhaps it needs a new certificate.  You should talk to your network administrator about the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can try `git config http.sslVerify false` to turn it off.

Comment: While this will solve the problem, it will also make the entire connection insecure, which is a bad idea from a security point of view.

Comment: I knew this option, it works,  as already mentioned, it makes the connection insecure. I would rather want to fix the actual problem